# How to get timeseries partition data in single query sqlalchemy python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using the Postgresql database with sqlalchemy orm in python. I want represent sales graph for a week. I am storing the `unix timestamp` of the sale at any any moment in DB. Now in the x-axis, I have 6 points like sat-sun, sun-mon... Thu-Fri. Now i can get the result for exaple sat-sun by following query:-

```
result = db.query(SalesTable).filter(and_(SalesTable.when_in_unix_time >= self.start_time,
                 SalesTable.when_in_unix_time <= self.end_time)).all()
```

Now i need to do **6 query to get 7 days aka 1 week's result**, right? How to get the result in one query as a partition of from one day to next day?

Comment: Do you want a pure SQL solution or a Python solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i just want to figure out by which expression of SQL i can get the result in one query. SQL or Python's sqlalchemy syntax both will work for me, mate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually i clicked the wrong version of postgresql when choosing tag. my bad!

Comment: Unrelated, but: in general timestamp values should be stored in columns defined as `timestamp`  or `timestamptz`. Using a unix epoch is generally [not such a good idea](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/)